# .NET MAUI toolkit expander

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, maui, expander, maui-community-toolkit

I have Xamarin. Forms project. In that project I have community toolkit nuget, using this package I have added CollapseAnimationLength and ExpandAnimationLength propeties in expander. Now I am going to convert the project Xamarin. Forms to MAUI. But I am facing error while adding CollapseAnimationLength and ExpandAnimationLength propeties in expander using community toolkit in MAUI. How resolve this error in MAUI.

xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"

<xct:Expander x:Name="Fab" Margin="12" CollapseAnimationLength="0" ExpandAnimationLength="100" />

Any alternative for accessing CollapseAnimationLength and ExpandAnimationLength propeties in MAUI.

Comment: You cannot access something that isn't there.

Comment: Maui for now does not have these properties

Answer (score 0):

> Now I am going to convert the project Xamarin. Forms to MAUI. But I am facing error while adding CollapseAnimationLength and ExpandAnimationLength propeties in expander using community toolkit in MAUI. Any alternative for accessing CollapseAnimationLength and ExpandAnimationLength propeties in MAUI.

Unfortunately no, MAUI Community Toolkit Expander does not have a property similar to CollapseAnimationLength which Xamarin Community Toolkit Expander does have. Refer to official doc: [Expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/expander).

You can raise an issue or feature request on [CommunityToolkit/Maui GitHub](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues).

Comment: In addition, you can try [.NET MAUI Expander](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/new-dotnet-maui-expander-control.aspx#Animation) by sf.